# Creating a Dynamic Distribution List for +1 'starts with' filter-items

Tags: outbound-email, audience-manager, 2013-sp1-hr1

Is it possible to somehow create a dynamic distribution list that allows for a check of more than one entry in the *starts with* filter?

Seems when you select *starts with* there is no (visible) way to construct an OR (have tried: `IN or CA or US` || `IN, CA, US` || `IN CA US`)?

I wondered if there was a way to string 1+ Dynamic Distribution lists (or similar) together (as an address book or another Dynamic Dist List)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not currently supported, I'm afraid.

Your best bet is to use Keywords instead of a text field, as you can then choose whether the Contacts need to have any (the default) or all (check the box in the UI labeled "Limit results...") of the Keywords to be included in the list.